# sorting list items with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to use the JQuery UI Sortable plugin to allow a user to change the order or list items by dragging them with the mouse. The page in question is available [here](http://www.iol.ie/~murtaghd/bug/myPreferences.htm).

The relevant JQuery code is in webapp.js

```
$("#preferences_list").sortable({
            placeholder: "placeholder",
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            update: function(event, ui) {
                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize", {key:'list'});
                $.post("/mypreferences/reorder/", order);
            }
        });
$("#preferences_list").disableSelection();
```

This should enable the user to re-order the categories by using the [image: arrow image] to drag them up or down (and when a category is dropped in a new position an AJAX request is fired).

The code above looks the same as that shown on the [sortable plugin's demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/), but for some reason it's not working at all

Comment: Output from firebug? Error messages? WHYT?

Comment: I provided a link to the page itself, so should be able to see all that yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be other issues, but first change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myPreferences_files/jquery-ui-sortable-1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="myPreferences_files/jquery-ui-widget-1.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myPreferences_files/jquery-ui-widget-1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="myPreferences_files/jquery-ui-sortable-1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got sortable.js loading before widget.js.  Sortable depends on widget, so widget.js must be included first.  Just reorder your script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Look with Firebug on the page you created: there are 4 errors. For example:

> jquery-ui-sortable-1.js:17  - Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'widget'

Are you sure you have *jquery.ui.widget.js*?